# Is implicitly casting objects via function parameters expensive?

Tags: c#

Is implicitly casting objects via function parameters expensive?

For example

```
Class MyClass : IClass
```

and the function takes an IClass but instead I give it an MyClass Variable.

```
MyFunction(IClass myClass) {}
MyClass test = new MyClass()
MyFunction(test);
```

Is this performance hindering just like normal casting?

EDIT:

I edited it to a case that would compile, sorry. How does this look now?

Comment: No, there is no performance implication of any kind, as [your code would not compile](http://ideone.com/qFsdK7).

Comment: That doesn't compile because any number of classes that aren't `MyClass` could also implement `IClass`, so we can never be sure that the `IClass` being passed is definitely a `MyClass`. Therefore the compiler will complain.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is concerning a flawed premise.

Comment: I edited it, and replaced the example code with a case that would compile.

Comment: I'd venture that your time might be better spent on higher level issues than asking about the (negligible) cost of casting without a particular problem in mind. You should always code for clarity rather than convoluting your code to gain some unmeasured time. You'll end up with complicated code that probably won't run any faster. It's next to impossible to know where your code will "run slow". Don't try and guess. Measure once you've written correct code, then act accordingly.

Comment: That is not a cast. It is an implicit conversion. Implicit conversions of objects to base classes or interfaces are very cheap (usually zero cost) because they can be resolved at compile time.